# grpc status not sent from server interceptor to client

Tags: spring, error-handling, interceptor, grpc-java

In grpc server interceptor, I want to catch the exceptions and send the full stack trace to the client.

```
public void onHalfClose() {
  try {
    super.onHalfClose();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    handleException(ex);
    throw ex;
  }
}


private void handleException(Exception exception) {
  var status = Status.fromThrowable(exception);
  // status.cause has the full stack trace now
  // Add requestHeaders with new metadata.
  call.close(status, requestHeaders);
}
```

On the client-side, I have a `ClientInterceptor`, which intercepts the `OnClose()`

```
@Override
public void onClose(Status status, Metadata requestHeaders) {
  // status is different, requestHeaders include the added info
  super.onClose(status, requestHeaders);
}
```

I am able to receive the headers, but not the status. I could copy the entire stack trace as a string in one of the headers, but its has problems of header size limitations of 8K, which is not enough for extra long stack traces I get in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Status`'s cause is dropped and [not serialized and sent](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/cb8b0679add2d389cfd15cd34e11c3577e3de2cb/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/AbstractServerStream.java#L130-L137) to the client. Only the Status code and its description are sent. So you will never receive the stacktrace.

You can make the augment the Status description with the stacktrace string ([`Status.augmentDescription`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Status.html#augmentDescription-java.lang.String-)) if you want to preserve it and have it sent to the client side.

But anyways, all the Status information is serialized in the response trailer, which needs to conform the 8 KB size limit. No matter where the stacktrace is embedded.